# Assigning a variable data to another

Tags: java

I'm this function multiple times and I'm passing the `stats` to a list and I'm returning the data using `return statisticsList.get(statisticsList.size() - 1); or could be index 0 because there is only one stat`.

This is totally stupid because I could simply do

```
Statistics statistics;
```

and then

```
statistics = stats;
```

and returning `statistics`instead of `statisticsList.get(statisticsList.size() - 1);`.But this doesn't work because it says `statistics` is expected to be final. If I put final I can't assign stats to it.

So how do return `stats` the simplest way possible making sure `.awaitCompletion();` is executed??

```
 public static Statistics getStatistics(String environmentName) {
    Container container = getContainer(environmentName);
    List<Statistics> statisticsList = new LinkedList<>();

    try {
        dockerClient().statsCmd(container.getId()).exec(new ResultCallbackTemplate<StatsCallback, Statistics>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(Statistics stats) {
                System.out.println(stats);
                statisticsList.add(stats);
                if(statisticsList.size() > 0 ) {
                    onComplete();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                super.onComplete();
            }
        }).awaitCompletion();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return statisticsList.get(statisticsList.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: What is "it" in `it says statistics is expected to be final.`?

Comment: Intellij IDE...

Comment: Create your own `ResultCallback` that sets a `CompletableFuture` and retrieve the result from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can still add elements to a final list. You just can't reassign it with another reference.